# Can you edit multiple videos at the same time using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert many videos into avi with this code.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 output.avi
```

Is there any way i can apply this to 6 videos at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## One big command

You can use one command if you prefer:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i video4.mp4 -i video5.mp4 -i video6.mp4 \
-map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 video1.avi \
-map 1 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 video2.avi \
-map 2 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 video3.avi \
-map 3 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 video4.avi \
-map 4 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 video5.avi \
-map 5 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 video6.avi
```

## Bash loop

Or use a bash *for loop* for "batch" encoding which is what I would do because it is less typing. It doesn't encode them all at once but one-by-one.

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 "${f%.*}.avi"; done
```

#### Speed

As for encoding speed, with `mpeg4`, the fastest method is likely zx485's answer. My two examples should be about the same speed as each other, but it can depend on your hardware, number of inputs, etc.

Comment: So what are the parts that I have to add into the code?

Comment: So for example I have 6 videos named video1.mp4, video2.mp4, and so on. What would be the exact code I type in?

Comment: when I type it in exactly the way you wrote it, its tells me "f was unexpected at this time"

Comment: @paulST 1) Nothing. Copy and paste. 2) I renamed the examples to use your exact file names. 3) Works for me. That sounds like a Windows error. Are you actually using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

A simple approach of *running them all at the same time* would be to call them as background processes:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 output1.avi &
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 output2.avi &
ffmpeg -i input3.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 output3.avi &
ffmpeg -i input4.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 output4.avi &
ffmpeg -i input5.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 output5.avi &
ffmpeg -i input6.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 output6.avi &
```

The `&` at the end of each command line designates the commands as background processes.

**But be aware that these processes "fight" for processor resources.**

Comment: I am trying to prevent typing out the code multiple times. I just say 6 because i have many folders of videos that have 6 videos each.

Comment: @paulST: I modified my answer. Just put these lines in a script file and execute the script (of course with the appropriate paths of input and output names) and it will function as described in your question.

Comment: how do i put it in a script file?

Comment: @paulST: You pretty much copy the above code section into a (text) file, make it executable with `chmod +x [fileName]` and execute it. Of course, the filenames need to be adjusted to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to encode whole videos under cwd recursively.

```
find -name '*.avi' | sed 's/\.avi$//g' | xargs --replace ffmpeg -i "{}.mp4" -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 "{}.avi"
```

And if you want to encode in parallel, you can use this command.

```
find -name '*.avi' | sed 's/\.avi$//g' | xargs --replace ffmpeg -i "{}.mp4" -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 "{}.avi"
```

`-P` option of xargs means the number of processes.
Perhaps, `ffmpeg` command is supposed to use thread to compile video in parallel.
as others mentions, these process also "fight" for processor resource.

Comment: wrote it wrongly.

Comment: second comand is

Comment: find -name '*.avi' | sed 's/\.avi$//g' | xargs -P4 --replace ffmpeg -i "{}.mp4" -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -aspect 16:9 "{}.avi"

Comment: correct it! you can edit your answer...